# How to upload a file in jsp form without submit button action

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I have a JSP form page with multiple fields and an file upload field before submit.

I need to upload file into path without submit action in JSP. how i can achieve this? I have tried different ajax method etc. but i don't see any action happening.

I have a jsp page here, the upload will show up based on one of the dropdown value. till there its working fine. I have used submit action for upload here. but also tried Ajax call etc. nothing working :( ideal goal is to upload file without submit action.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<html>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image:
        url('https://cdn.crunchify.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Crunchify.bg_.300.png');
}
</style>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>First JSP Servlet Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center" style="margin-top: 50px;">

        <form action="FirstwebServlet">
        <br> Please select the option
            : <select required="required" name="sel" id="selType">
                <option value="None">Choose from the list</option>
                <option value="MyReport">MyReport</option>
                <option value="Myview">Myview</option>
                <option value="mycustom">mycustom</option>

            </select> <br>


            <form id="upload-form" class="upload-box" action="/Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id="otherType" style="display: none;">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file1" />
    <span id="upload-error" class="error">${uploadError}</span>
    <input type="submit" id="upload-button" value="upload" />
    </div>
</form>


            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>

    </div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#upload-form').ajaxForm({
            success: function(msg) {
                alert("File has been uploaded successfully");
            },
            error: function(msg) {
                $("#upload-error").text("Couldn't upload file");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
    <script
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    ‌​
    <script>
        $('#selType').change(function(){
               selection = $(this).val();    
               switch(selection)
               { 
                   case 'Mycustomtemplate':
                       $('#otherType').show();
                       break;
                   default:
                       $('#otherType').hide();
                       break;
               }
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery,you can do submit on select of File:

```
$('#file').change(function() {
  $('#upload-form').submit();
});


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="upload-form" action="/Upload">
  <input type="file" id="file" value="Go" />
</form>
```